# p5.js autoclicker calling

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a simple question maybe, I was for days looking for solution and don't want to waste your time, but isn't work for me so I'm here now.

Im using P5JS, and I wanted to create auto click function.
There how I call an button in sketch.js file

```
 var button1 = createButton("Generator");
  button1.mousePressed(banana);
  button1.id('autoclick');
```

Here you can see how I call in index.html
Im trying something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var iteration = true;
var time = new Date();
var delay = 5000; // 5 secondes

while(iteration) {
    if(time.getTime() + 5000 < new Date().getTime()) {
         iteration = false;
    }
}
document.getElementByID('autoclick').click();
      // noprotect
</script>
```

Maybe I complicate to much? any suggetions? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is blocking, which means that while Javascript is running your `while` loop, it will not be able to execute any other code. You want to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) for your purposes.

For example,

```js
setInterval(() => console.log("hello!"), 1000)
```